# How to count the number of times a loop occurs?

Tags: c++

I'm creating a program that can find the sum from 1 to a number entered by a user using two methods. The first method is by physically adding every number between, and the second method is through the following formula: `(x*(x+1))/2`. I wrote both the functions out, but I can't figure out how to count the number of operations that occur for each method. For instance, there's a total of 3 mathematical operations that happen using the second formula. I've attempted to count the operations (shown below) but I'm not sure what exactly to use for this.

```
int sumEquation (int x, int operationCount) { 
    operationCount =3;
    return (x*(x+1))/2;
}
```

```
int sumOfDigits(int x, int operationCount) { 
    operationCount = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
        sum += i;
        operationCount +=2;
    } 
    return sum ; 
}
```

```
int main() {     
    int n;
    cout << "Enter a number: " ;
    cin >> n;
    int operationCount;    
    cout << "First Method" <<endl;    
    cout << "Result: " << sumOfDigits(n, operationCount) << " with "  << operationCount <<  " operations" << endl;             
    cout << "Second Method" <<endl;
    cout << "Result: " <<sumEquation(n, operationCount) << " with " << operationCount << " operations " <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use `operationCount` as an output parameter, which means you need to pass it by reference.

Comment: Please format your code. See [How do I format code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361)

Comment: Precision is important! *"I can't figure out how to count the number of operations that occur for each method."* -- no, you have figured that out. You have not, though, figured out how to get that count out of `sumEquation()` and `sumOfDigits()`.

Comment: It is still not clear what you want. Are you setting the `operationCount` manually in every function or do you want to automate it based on the operations happening in the function definition?
If you're doing it manually then you can either make `operationsCount` a `static` variable or pass it by reference or pass it by pointer.
If you want to automate the process you'll need to do some operator overloading and also define what mathematical operations you're targeting cuz I can see that there are still mathematical operations happening inside `someOfDigits()` which are not counted.

Answer (score 2):

Here either you can return a pair of ints in which one is the sum and one is the operation count. Or you can use an operation count variable as you have done. But then you will have to pass the variable through reference. Like-

```
int sumEquation (int x, int& operationCount) {
    operationCount =3;
    return (x*(x+1))/2;
}

int sumOfDigits(int x, int& operationCount) {
    operationCount = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
        sum += i;
        operationCount +=2;
    }
    return sum ;
}
```

Comment: @jwdonahue Why?? The answer is correct. Did you notice it is C++, not C?

Comment: @Eugene, so it is. I was definitely in C mode at the time, but your code would not compile, even as C++ (see my edit).

Comment: @jwdonahue - this was not my code. This is from @hazy007, a new contributor. You made a mistake and downvoted his correct answer, and now you are using a single typo (missing `{`) as a pretext to keep the downvote. You should undo it,

Comment: @Eugene, yup, I missed the down-vote. Should have removed it on my last visit.

Comment: @jwdonahue- Thanks for the edit. Sorry for the mistake. I should have tested the code.

Comment: @Eugene- Thanks for the support. I will take care next time.

Answer (score 2):

It's seems that you are already able to count the number of operations just fine but unable to return the result, so,

```cpp
std::pair<int, int> sumEquation (int x) { 
    int operationCount =3;
    return {(x*(x+1))/2, operationCount};
}
std::pair<int, int> sumOfDigits(int x) { 
    int operationCount = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
        sum += i;
        operationCount +=2;
    } 
    return {sum, operationCount}; 
}
int main() {     
    int n;
    std::cout << "Enter a number: " ;
    std::cin >> n; 
    std::cout << "First Method" << std::endl;  
    auto method1 = sumOfDigits(n); 
    std::cout << "Result: " << method1.first << " with "  << method1.second <<  " operations" << std::endl;             
    std::cout << "Second Method" << std::endl;
    auto method2 = sumEquation(n); 
    std::cout << "Result: " << method2.first << " with " << method2.second << " operations " << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Should do the trick. I used [std::pair](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair), but you could use other methods, like arrays, to achieve the same goal.

**Note:** Edited after [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66165902/how-to-count-the-number-of-times-a-loop-occurs/66166462#comment116979320_66166462) comment, here is the original code:

```cpp
pair<int, int> sumEquation (int x) { 
    int operationCount =3;
    return make_pair((x*(x+1))/2, operationCount);
}
pair<int, int> sumOfDigits(int x) { 
    int operationCount = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
        sum += i;
        operationCount +=2;
    } 
    return make_pair(sum, operationCount); 
}
int main() {     
    int n;
    cout << "Enter a number: " ;
    cin >> n; 
    cout << "First Method" <<endl;  
    pair<int, int> method1 = sumOfDigits(n); 
    cout << "Result: " << method1.first << " with "  << method1.second <<  " operations" << endl;             
    cout << "Second Method" <<endl;
    pair<int, int> method2 = sumEquation(n); 
    cout << "Result: " << method2.first << " with " << method2.second << " operations " <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are not showing an example of a good modern style. Your code is limited to C++98, and you also imply `using namespace std;`, which is not recommended. Starting from C++11, you could replace `make_pair()` with `{}` and use `auto` to declare `method1` and `method2` variables.

Comment: @Eugene Thanks! I've edited it. (However, the original question also implied `using namespace std;`)